# How do I get non default calendars to show up on iOS (iPhone/iPad)?

Tags: ios, google-calendar

I was able to connect my iPhone to multiple Google accounts and have the default calendars show up on my iPhone and iPad correctly.  But how do I get the non default google calendars to show up as well?

Comment: Is your question about syncing calendars or displaying them?  Are you seeing stagnant entries for those non-default calendars on your iOS device or are you not seeing the calendars at all?

Comment: @jaberg removed the syncing wording to prevent confusion. the non default calendars don't even appear. I actually found the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is a secret URL you have to visit to check off which calendars you want to appear on your iOS device.

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/iphoneselect